# Is it possible to declare two interdependent classes each in a separate file?

Tags: powershell, class, dependencies, code-organization

I have two PowerShell classes that are inter-dependent:

Class `A`:

```
class A {

   [int] hidden $i
   [B]   hidden $b_

   A([int] $i) {
     $this.i = $i
   }

   [void] set_b([B] $b) {
      $this.b_ = $b
   }

   [B] get_b() {
      return $this.b_
   }

   [int] get_i() {
      return $this.i
   }
}
```

and class `B`:

```
class B {

   [int] hidden $j
   [A]   hidden $a_

   B([int] $j) {
     $this.j = $j
   }


   [void] set_a([A] $a) {
      $this.a_ = $a
   }

   [A] get_a() {
      return $this.a_
   }

   [int] get_j() {
      return $this.j
   }
}
```

If I put both classes into the same source file, `A-and-B.ps1`, and dot-source the file:

```
. .\A-and-B.ps`
```

I am able to use these classes:

```
[A] $a = new-object A 42
[B] $b = new-object B 99

$b.set_a($a)
$a.set_b($b)

$a.get_b().get_a().get_i()
```

However, I want to put each class into its own file: `A.ps1` and `B.ps1`. Unfortunately, I cannot dot-source `A.ps1` because I receive `Unable to find type [B].` error messages (which I understand).

So I tried to forward-declare class `B` in `A.ps1`:

```
class B {}

class A {
   ...
```

which allowed to dot-source both files, `A.ps1` and `B.ps1`.

However, trying to use these classes results in the error message

> Cannot convert argument "b", with value: "B", for "set_b" to type "B": "Cannot convert the "B" value of type "B" to type "B"."

So, is there a way to put interdependent classes into their own source file in PowerShell?

Comment: I can think of a terrible way that we shouldn't use -> `invoke-expression ((gc A.ps1 -Raw)+(gc B.ps1 -Raw))`

Comment: @AdminOfThings lol I was thinking of another awful one `. ([scriptblock]::Create((Get-Content .\class* -Raw)))`

Comment: Maybe this is something [PSDepend](https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PSDepend) could help with. Seems like it would be inline with the intent of the module.